# setTimeout() multiple JQuery instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

So I have a block of about 10 lines of code in JQuery. the lines are all independent, and when I execute them (I just type them in the console, its an automated test) i need them to be delayed form each other, like with 2 seconds difference. I started by using JavaScript setTimeout() on each line, but for 10 separate lines of code i assume there's a sexier way to do so... Also JQuery DELAY doesn't work since these aren't effects. Any ideas? here's the general idea of my code block..

```
$("#tag1").trigger("click");

$('#tag2').val("some text");

$("#tag3").trigger("keyup");

$('#tag4 select option[value="4"]').prop('selected',true);

$("#tag5").val(6);

$('#tag6').val(3).change();

$('#tag7').val(30).change();

$('#tag8').val("2017-06-29");

$('#tag9').val("2015-06-29");

$('#tag10').val("This is the test tasks' description.");

$(".id1").trigger("click");

$(".id2").val("buy oranges");
```

As you can see all the tags and ID are unique...
any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like some automated testing, if so have you tried using something like Selenium? It has this functionality built in.

Comment: An array of anonymous functions would be one option. Pass them recursively to a function that uses `setTimeout` Slicing off the first one each time..

Comment: you can try with setInterval(function(){alert('HI')},2000).

Comment: It is actually automated testing, but due to some issues it[s impossible for us to use selenium, so i will have to build this code myself :)

Comment: If you can provide a sample of your page HTML, I can complete the working example below.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment: An array of anonymous functions would be one option. Pass them recursively to a function that uses `setTimeout` Slicing off the first one each time..

e.g. something like this (the test just prints the functions to console as the DOM elements are missing):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bnq6tppb/1/

```
var operations = [
    function () {
        $("#tag1").trigger("click");
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag2').val("some text");
    },
    function () {
        $("#tag3").trigger("keyup");
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag4 select option[value="4"]').prop('selected', true);
    },
    function () {
        $("#tag5").val(6);
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag6').val(3).change();
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag7').val(30).change();
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag8').val("2017-06-29");
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag9').val("2015-06-29");
    },
    function () {
        $('#tag10').val("This is the test tasks' description.");
    },
    function () {
        $(".id1").trigger("click");
    },
    function () {
        $(".id2").val("buy oranges");
}];
```

and use recursively with a timer:

```
function processoperations(ops){
    // Run the first operation
    ops[0]();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (ops.length > 1){
            // Go recursive after 2 seconds
            processoperations(ops.slice(1));
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

and start like this:

```
processoperations(operations);
```

This allows you to process *any* code at intervals. The alternative (as others mentioned) is an automated testing tool (like Selenium) *if this is actually a testing problem.* Update: You have mentioned you are not allowed to use Selenium.